# How to specify winget installation folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, package-management, windows-packagemanagement

I would like to use `winget`, on Windows 10, as a packet manager, it seems to work pretty well. However I have encountered a big inconvenience: I seem to be not able to specify the location of the installation folder. In the online documentation I have read that I should use `--location` to specify the location, so something like `winget install --id GitHub.Atom --location "C:\Program Files"` However this seems to accomplish nothing, and `Atom` still gets installed into the `AppData` local folder. I don't get what I am doing wrong here: should I use single quotes? Should I use no quotes at all? I have also tried to use the `--scope machine` specification, it should tell `winget` to install the program for all users. However it still gets installed into the local `AppData`.

---

What am I doing wrong? Not being able to specify the installation folder is a **huge** dealbreker for `winget`... And this package manager has been around for years at this point. If this is a bug it is simply inexcusable, or am I missing something?

Comment: `-l, --location` Location to install to (**if supported**).

Comment: I have researched Atom before it’s use of AppData is intentional

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? What are the reasons behind the use of that specific folder? Can you expand on it in an answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I saw that, but I don't get what Microsoft means by: "if supported"... What are the limitations? Where is the difficulty in installing something in a folder instead of another one?

Comment: @Noumeno I suspect **if supported** means the application you are trying to install supports a custom directory location.